# View user group limitation

Tags: azure-devops, settings, usergroups

We have a number of groups that come from Azure Active Directory.
Some groups contain more than 200 Users but the total is limited to 200.
Where can I set that all users are visible in the group so more than 200

Answer (score 0):

This is by design a currently only a design limitation.

Azure DevOps UI will only list the first 200 members of an AAD group.

The limitation is only in what members we display, it does not impact the actual permission assignment. If you need to find the related user, you should search on the specific user directly.

I can fully understand your requirement, I suggest that you can create a suggestion ticket in the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest).